# Kotlin: implicit conversion from Int to nullable Double fails in reflection

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I was trying to convert a `Map<String, Any>` to data class instance:

```kotlin
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val weight: Double?,
)

fun test() {
    val map = mapOf(
        "name" to "steven",
        "age" to 30,
        "weight" to 60,
    )
    
    val ctor = Person::class.constructors.first();
    val params = ctor.parameters.associateWith {
        map[it.name]
    }
        
    val instance = ctor.callBy(params)
    println(instance)
}
```

The code above throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` because `60` is passed to `weight` as an Int, and kotlin does not support implicit conversion.

Then I change the type of `weight` to non-nullable `Double`

```kotlin
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val weight: Double, // !
)
```

and that works, even `60F` works too.

My question is:

1. Why implicit conversion works only when type is non-nullable?
2. How to do implicit conversion when type is nullable?

Comment: "even 60F works too." Cannot reproduce on the JVM.

Comment: I mean "60F" is a literal float value and can be passed to non-nullable Double. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Kotlin/JVM...

After digging a bit into how `callBy` is implemented on the JVM, I found that it [eventually](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/calls/CallerImpl.kt#L39) calls [`Constructor.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)). The documentation for that says:

> Individual parameters are automatically unwrapped to match primitive formal parameters, and both primitive and reference parameters are subject to method invocation conversions as necessary.

When you use the non-nullable `Double` in Kotlin as a parameter type, it is translated to the primitive type `double` in the JVM world. However, if you use the nullable type `Double?`, it is translated to the reference type wrapper `java.lang.Double`. This is because the primitive type `double` cannot be null. A similar thing happens for `Int` and `Int?`.

The "method invocation conversions" that the `newInstance` docs mentioned (which I think is referring to [the list of conversions allowed in an invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)) does not include a conversion from `int` to `java.lang.Double`. After all, this Java code does not compile:

```
public static void foo(Double d) {}

// ...

int x = 1;
foo(x)l
```

But it would have compiled if `foo` had taken the primitive `double`.

As for your second question, I can't think of anything better than just checking each argument and parameter type manually, and performing the conversion explicitly for each case.

If you can change `Person`, I'd suggest adding a secondary constructor that takes a non-nullable `Double`, and change the calling code to choose an appropriate constructor.

Or if you *really* don't like choosing constructors, change the existing one to take `Number?`, and convert it to an appropriate numeric type using the `toXXX` methods before using it.